# Bind web user control property in markup

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm sure it's elementary but I can't figure it out.

This does **not** work - the the binding expression is passed as string to the control:

```
<uc:usercontrol runtat="server" message='<%#Me.protectedVariable%>'/>
```

The code behind include a Page.Databind() call in page_load.

But this does work:

```
<uc:usercontrol runat="server" id="usercontrol1"/>
```

And in code behind page_load:

```
usercontrol1.message = Me.protectedVariable
```

Do I have to bind from the code-behind? Is this a page life cycle issue?

Comment: "Does not work" in what way? BTW, the first one, if it worked, would occur during the `DataBinding` event, not the `Load` event.

Comment: The control's message property is '<%#Me.protectedVariable%>' instead of the variable value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moved the Page.DataBind() to the PreRender event handler an the problem was solved. Seems that properties of the web user controls are not yet bound at page_load.

Answer (score 1):

code looks ok.

```
 <uc:usercontrol runtat="server" message='<%#Me.protectedVariable%>'/>
```

should work.

protectedVariable should be set before calling Page.Databind();

Can you tell, what exact problem is.

Comment: protectedVariable is set before calling page.databind, but the problem is that the binding expression is passed to the control instead of the value.